# ASP.NET Core : Google Chrome does not display anything into the JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am currently developping a project for a customer. This project is using Blazor WebAssembly, with MudBlazor. That means we are using .NET Core (7, to be precise).

And, for a reason I cannot spot, my JavaScript console does not display anything, which make JavaScript debugging a pain.
Just, if you ask : no, I have no choice but to use JavaScript in my project despite the fact Blazor was made so you basically do not need any.

As I am out of solutions, and it is greatly slowing me down in my work. I would like to know if you ever had this issue, and if so, how did you solve it.

If that can help :

- The console still displays C# errors
- It still has some Visual Studio build-in messages, that does not help
- It also can display XHttpRequests

But for JS debugging, nothing works

I just want my JavaScript errors being displayed in the console. For example, $ not existing when I forgot jQuery, or like "Unrecognized method" when calling the wrong function.

I tried :

- Turning script debugging on
- Enabling JavaScript debugging in the options
- Putting every debug output to "detailed"
- On my browser, deactivating every filter and so...
- I even tried putting console.log inside my code, and *they are not even written*

Comment: "I have no choice but to use JavaScript in my project despite the fact Blazor was made so you basically do not need any" sounds like a high time to change the PM/employer.

Comment: I would like you not to juge my team or my employer. The constraint is not coming from them, but from the technology I am using.
We are using the Google Maps Api, and as it is using JavaScript...You are giving the answer.

Comment: Maybe you should kindly consider changing the technology?

Comment: @maciek I would like to, but the problem is that the graphic Google Maps Autocomplete component is only available in JavaScript. And even if I wanted to avoid the utilization of JS, I would be loosing to much time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed my issue by putting all the script into a dedicated JS file instead of a nested script tag in the .razor file. It worked like a charm.

Edit : It looks like that, by either Razor's or Visual studio's fault, script tags are not executed anymore. So the only solution is to move everything into JS objects as methods, and to call them using the JSRuntime